# jQuery - Multi Level Selector

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

```
<ul id="L1">
    <li id="L1_1"></li>
    <li id="L1_2">
        <ul id="L2">
            <li id="L2_1"></li>            
            <li id="L2_2"></li>
            <li id="L2_3"></li>
            <li id="L2_4"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="L1_3"></li>
</ul>
```

Can you jquery experts provide me with the selector to select say id="L2_3"?

$("#L2_3") won't work unfortunately due to my specific situation with this 3rd party library I'm working with (Kendo / Telerik / whatever they're calling themselves these days)

Following kinda works but only for one level (I need it to select deeper):

```
$('[id="L1_1"]'
```

Comment: if your `li` has exactly the id `L2_3`, I don't see any reason why `$("#L2_3")` does not work. Also looks like you are expressing the problem in a confusing way.

Comment: yeah, as I said it has to do with the underlying Panelbar (not Jquery); Panelbar doesn't know about $("#L2_3") until its parent is expanded first (eventhough, #L2_3 is actually rendered and is part of DOM; it's just a shortcoming); as per my answer, I have to expand the parent, then its child all the way down to the node I want expanded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the nature of Kendo Panelbar,  I can't simply say:

```
panelbar.expand($('[id="L2_4"]'))
```

to circumnavigate this short coming here's how i'm going to do it:

```
panelBar.select($('[id="L1_2"]'));
var item = panelBar.select();
panelBar.expand(item);

panelBar.select($('[id="L2_4"]'));
item = panelBar.select();
panelBar.expand(item);
```